# Weird UICollectionView orientation transitions

Tags: ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm using a collection view to show photos in an iPad app. The cells are subclasses of `UICollectionViewCell`. The cell is using auto layout, with fixed space from all sides.

Now when the orientation changes, the cells becomes very small at first. Then it resizes to the proper size. But should be possible to keep the same size, it's really ugly like this.

Any thoughts on this problem?